# how to check whether tts has finished speaking?

Tags: java, android

I've created a Text To Speech android application. I want to change button text from **speak** to **stop** and then again to **speak** when it finishes speaking.

It has two buttons- **clear all** and **speak**. **speak** should change to **stop** on click and again to **speak** when speaking is done.

[Activity screenshot (UI)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4vyU.png)

I searched a lot on StackOverflow as well as the web including their official docs but couldn't find a solution to fit into my program.

Please help me I'm new to android.
ThankYou!

```
  //text to speech

    t1 = new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInit(int status) {

            if (status != TextToSpeech.ERROR)
                t1.setLanguage(Locale.UK);

                }
    });




    //onClick
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String toSpeak = ed1.getText().toString();
            if(flag==0) { //flag variable to check state and to change button text
                if(toSpeak=="")
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Empty, enter something!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Speaking", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    t1.speak(toSpeak, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                    flag = 1;
                    b1.setText("Stop");
                    flag = 1;
                }
            }
            else {

                flag=0;
                String te=ed1.getText().toString();
                ed1.setText("");
                toSpeak = ed1.getText().toString();
                ed1.setText(te);
                t1.speak(toSpeak, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                b1.setText("Play");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();




            }

        }
    });


//clear all button. clears the text field and changes text on the button1 to play
        b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

                ed1.setText("");
                b1.setText("Play");flag=0;
        }
        });
```

Comment: Welcome to SO... For future questions, please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Don't forget to setup `utteranceId`. Without this id listener is not called. `textToSpeech.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, "utteranceId")`

Answer (score 4):

Don't use 'TextToSpeech.OnUtteranceCompletedListener' use the one below:

```
  @Override
  public void onInit(int status) {
    if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
    yourTTS.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(new UtteranceProgressListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDone(String utteranceId) {
            // Log.d("YourActivity", "TtS Compeleted ");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(String utteranceId) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStart(String utteranceId) {
        }
      });
     } else {
    Log.e("YourActivity", " TTS Failed!");
   }
}
```

[Deprecated TextToSpeech.OnUtteranceCompletedListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech#setOnUtteranceProgressListener(android.speech.tts.UtteranceProgressListener))

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
textToSpeech=new TextToSpeech(this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
    @Override
    public void onInit(int status) {
        if (status==TextToSpeech.SUCCESS){
            int result=textToSpeech.setLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH);

            if (result==TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA||result==TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED){
                Log.i("TextToSpeech","Language Not Supported");
            }

            textToSpeech.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(new UtteranceProgressListener() {
                @Override
                public void onStart(String utteranceId) {
                    Log.i("TextToSpeech","On Start");
                }

                @Override
                public void onDone(String utteranceId) {
                    Log.i("TextToSpeech","On Done");
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(String utteranceId) {
                    Log.i("TextToSpeech","On Error");
                }
            });

        }else {
            Log.i("TextToSpeech","Initialization Failed");
        }
    }
});

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    textToSpeech.speak(text,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,null,TextToSpeech.ACTION_TTS_QUEUE_PROCESSING_COMPLETED);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Override  `TextToSpeech.OnUtteranceCompletedListener` method. For complete documentation [here.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.OnUtteranceCompletedListener)
Listener that will be called when the TTS service has completed synthesizing an utterance.

```
  @Override
    public void onUtteranceCompleted(String utteranceId) {
        Log.i("CALLBACK", utteranceId);

    }
```

Hope  it will help you!!